# Batch command and error handling

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, command

I am using this code in a batch file:

```
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain | findstr /i %group%"') do set /a i=%i%+1
```

It looks like no matter what %user% you type in it will still set %i%+1 equaling 1...   even if the %user% is not found.

If the %user% is not found, NET USER reports saying the user was not found, but because %i%=1 it continues on in the script.

How would I go about getting this to work?
If the %user% is not found in /Domain then %i% needs to = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f %%f in ('"net user %user% /domain ^| findstr /i %group%"') do set /a i=%i%+1
```

you need to escape the pipe as it is with higher prio than for loop.

Comment: Also, the DO clause could be simplified to `set /a i+=1`

Comment: @npocmaka  From what I see you only escaped the pipe.  When I add the escape (carrot) it reports  /I is an unknown option in NET.  This error happens whether the user is good or not.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: `for /f %%f in ('net user %user% /domain ^| findstr /i "%group%"') do set /a i+=1` see double quoting

Comment: Or even `'net user %user% /domain 2^>NUL ^| findstr /i "%group%"'` to suppress displaying error messages...